# Is there any option to create keyword with both normal and embedded arguments in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework, keyword-argument

Is there any way to create keyword having both normal and embedded arguments in Robot framework?
If so, then please tell how?

Answer (score 1):

The user guide says you cannot, read it [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#embedded-argument-syntax):

> Keywords using embedded arguments cannot take any "normal" arguments (specified with [Arguments] setting) but otherwise they are created just like other user keywords.

So a short answer is no.

Another way you can test this is you experiment, if I type:

```
*** Keywords ***
Log ${arg} Into Console
    [Arguments]    ${msg}
    Log To Console    ${arg}    
    Log To Console    ${msg}
```

then RED shows this error:

> The setting '[Arguments]' is duplicated. There are variables defined in keyword name

That answers your question as well.